# Child component props not reflecting state change from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The part of my app in question is utilizing 4 components, 1 parent and 3 children. As expected, the parent component handles all state and passes values to child components via props.

The parent component contains methods for updating state changes, also passed down via props. The child components do not have state other than component methods, they use only props for visual data.

The problem I’m having is that when I call the method to update parent state, the parent state is updated successfully (verified via the console), however the child component, which reflects this state via its props, doesn’t render the state change visually.

The code is below which I’ll do my best to explain:

Parent component update state method:

```
handleUpvoteState(blurtIndex) {
    let blurts = [...this.state.followingBlurts],
        updatedBlurt = {...blurts[blurtIndex]};
    updatedBlurt.vote++;
    blurts[blurtIndex] = updatedBlurt;
    this.setState({
        followingBlurts: blurts
    });
    console.log(this.state.followingBlurts[blurtIndex].vote); // State change reflected.
}
```

Parent component passing state to child props:

```
<LazyBlurtsPanel
     appendDate={this.state.appendDate}
     random={this.state.randomize} 
     blurts={this.state.followingBlurts} 
     handleLazyState={this.handleLazyState}
     handleUpvoteState={this.handleUpvoteState}
     lazyElement='lzyfollowing'
     apiMethod={this.state.apiMethod}
     currentUser={false}
 />
```

The lazy panel component (above) then sends data to footer child via props:

```
<BlurtFooter 
   voteCount={this.props.blurts[i].vote}
   currentUser={this.props.currentUser}
   blurtId={this.props.blurts[i]._id}
   blurtIndex={i}
   handleUpvoteState={this.props.handleUpvoteState}
 />
```

When I call

```
this.props.handleUpvoteState(index)
```

in my child footer component, the parent state is successfully updated. However, the footer component doesn't re-render to reflect the parent's updated state.

Here's the footer component code that isn't getting re-rendered:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="blurt-panel-footer">
           <UpvoteCount voteCount={this.props.voteCount}/>
```

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT: There was some confusion as to how blurtfooter is called, so I'm including the code for how the panel is built inside a loop within LazyBlurtPanel component. Here's the code for that:

```
for(let i=numRendered; i<renderCount; i++) {
  if (this.props.blurts[i]) {
    renderBlurts.push(
         <div className='blurt-panel' id={(((i + 1) % 6) === 0) ? this.props.lazyElement : 'false'} key={i}>
              <BlurtHeader blurt={this.props.blurts[i]} />
              <div className='blurt-panel-body'>
                  <Sanitizer dirty={ this.props.blurts[i].text } />
                  {
                      (this.props.blurts[i].blurtImg !== 'false')? <img src={'/images/blurt/' + this.props.blurts[i].blurtImg} /> : ''
                  }
              </div>
              <BlurtFooter 
                  voteCount={this.props.blurts[i].vote}
                  currentUser={this.props.currentUser}
                  blurtId={this.props.blurts[i]._id}
                  blurtIndex={i}
                  handleUpvoteState={this.props.handleUpvoteState}
                  key={this.props.blurts[i]._id} //Tried with and without key here..
              />
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: `let blurts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.followingBlurts));` try this.

Comment: @sk01 my initial state sets followingBlurts to an array... Why would I switch to object notation?? As mentioned in my question, the state actually updates without issue. Thanks though!

Comment: the state change is asynchronous. if it was working properly, the state change should not be reflected in console. The problem here is when you use spread operator, the array reference is same. So you are directly making change to that array. Json stringify will solve the problem.

Comment: @sk01 I was a bit misleading in my description. The state change is reflected in the console, but it's always one number behind (due to async behavior you mentioned, good observation btw), nonetheless I can verify it is updating the state after the second button press (upvote). And I'm making changes directly to the array only, which is a shallow copy of state array... Just tried your solution for the sake of saking, no luck my friend.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` in the `render()` method of your `LazyBlurtsPanel` to see if it is being rerendered after the state change. If I'm right you are rendering `BlurtFooter` in a loop, then you shoud see a warning about missing key property. Not sure if it can cause this problem, but try adding `key={this.props.blurts[i]._id}`

Comment: @DimitriL. great idea. Yes `LazyBlurtPanel` is being re-rendered, however the footer is not. The thing is, the footer is nested in a `<div>` which does contain a `key={i}` property. I tried setting key in the nested footer as well just to try it, no luck. And yes `LazyBlurtPanel` uses a loop that builds the panels one by one.

Comment: Is the footer a PureComponent? If so try changing it to a Component to test

Comment: @tic The footer is a regular component... Which is how I verified that it is not re-rendering on state change. If I add a console log in the render method of footer I get nothing (except on initial render)...

Comment: @silencedogood Is your component `class BlurtFooter extends Component` or `class BlurtFooter extends PureComponent`. I'm guessing `Component` from your answer?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: @tic Sorry I misunderstood I edited my previous comment. Yes it is a `Component` not a `PureComponent`

Comment: So for clarity, the order of components is `Parent > LazyBlurtsPanel  > BlurtFooter`? When using `setState` in `Parent`, then a `console.log` in the `render` of all 3 components, `Parent` shows `log`, `LazyBlurtsPanel` shows `log`, but `BlurtFooter` does not show it?

Comment: @tic yup 100% correct. The `BlurtFooter` uses another functional component (tallying total components here to 4) to actually display the vote count and upvote button, but it's super simplistic and not relevant here.

Comment: Just for clarity (I don't think should fix anything, can you update your function to ```handleUpvoteState(blurtIndex) {
 const followingBlurts = [...this.state.followingBlurts];
 const updatedBlurt = followingBlurts[blurtIndex];
 followingBlurts[blurtIndex] = { ...updatedBlurt, vote: updatedBlurt.vote + 1 };
 this.setState({ followingBlurts });
}```

Comment: @tic I tried it, no difference unfortunately thx though!

Comment: I'm confused about how you called `BlurtFooter` as there are things like `blurtId={this.props.blurts[i]._id}`. Is this in a loop? The loop should look like `{ this.props.blurts.map((blurt, index) => (<BlurtFooter key={blurt._id} blurtId={blurt._id} blurtIndex={index} />)) }` (with the extra props)

Comment: Make sure to add the `key` above ^^

Comment: @tic I updated the question to include how the `BlurtFooter` is called. You're not too far off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing how `BlurtFooter` is called. Even if this doesn't fix it it will still be more maintainable code

```js
render() {
  const { currentUser, blurts, lazyElement, handleUpvoteState } = this.props;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {
        blurts.filter(x => x).map((blurt, index) => (
          <div className="blurt-panel" id={(((index + 1) % 6) === 0) ? lazyElement : 'false'} key={blurt._id}>
              <BlurtHeader blurt={blurt} />
              <div className="blurt-panel-body">
                  <Sanitizer dirty={blurt.text} />
                  {
                      blurt.blurtImg !== 'false' &&
                      <img src={`/images/blurt/${blurt.blurtImg}`} />
                  }
              </div>
              <BlurtFooter 
                  voteCount={blurt.vote}
                  currentUser={currentUser}
                  blurtId={blurt._id}
                  blurtIndex={index}
                  handleUpvoteState={handleUpvoteState}
              />
          </div>
        )
      }
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

There are a lot of other improvements that can be made, but see how that works, especially setting `key` correctly is a must.

I'm not sure what that `id` is on the `div` but that looks fishy as well and shouldn't be there.

Also the part `blurts.filter(x => x)` shouldn't be needed, so state should be improved to not need that

**Updated**: Make sure to take latest code above

Comment: This indirectly helped me solve my problem, essentially by forcing me to take a closer look at my lazyloader. I was utilizing state in a previous rendition, and I didn't entirely remove the code which was causing some type of strange state conflict. Honestly, I think I was actually _under_ complicating the matter, as there's a lot going on in my lazyloader. Your improvements all seem valid except that the reason I use an array var with loop (vs `.map` ) is because I need to dynamically add more items to the array as the user scrolls. Thanks a bunch you really helped me out here.

Answer (score 0):

State should always update in a nonmutating way. This way  react core library could understand there is a change in data.
Array and objects use reference pointers in memory. So even if we update a value inside  those reffrence type variables it won't affect the original memory location of those variables.
So create a new variable in memory and copy the state that you need to update and then set the state by using the new variable. This way we can avoid this issue. 
Also you can create a nonmutating structure using modern es6 + methods.